# error message['OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute '_drop_idx_after_grouping']

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

[ 2024-03-23 21:24:51,407 ] 96 werkzeug - INFO - [31m[1mWARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m

- Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
- Running on http://192.168.16.14:5000
  [ 2024-03-23 21:24:51,407 ] 96 werkzeug - INFO - [33mPress CTRL+C to quit[0m
  [ 2024-03-23 21:25:05,643 ] 96 werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2024 21:25:05] "GET /predictdata HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  [ 2024-03-23 21:25:06,049 ] 96 werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2024 21:25:06] "GET /predictdata HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  [ 2024-03-23 21:25:17,418 ] 825 app - ERROR - Exception on /predictdata [POST]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\result_predict\src\pipeline\predict_pipeline.py", line 19, in predict
  data_scaled=preprocessor.transform(features)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_set_output.py", line 295, in wrapped
  data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py", line 1014, in transform
  Xs = self._call_func_on_transformers(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py", line 823, in _call_func_on_transformers
  return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(jobs)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 67, in **call**
  return super().**call**(iterable_with_config)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1088, in **call**
  while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 901, in dispatch_one_batch
  self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 819, in _dispatch
  job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib_parallel_backends.py", line 208, in apply_async
  result = ImmediateResult(func)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib_parallel_backends.py", line 597, in **init**
  self.results = batch()
  ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 288, in **call**
  return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 288, in 
  return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\parallel.py", line 129, in **call**
  return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 1283, in _transform_one
  res = transformer.transform(X, **params.transform)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 905, in transform
  Xt = transform.transform(Xt, **routed_params[name].transform)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_set_output.py", line 295, in wrapped
  data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kolhe\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 1032, in transform
  if self._drop_idx_after_grouping is not None:
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute '_drop_idx_after_grouping'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kolhe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kolhe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kolhe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kolhe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kolhe\result_predict\app.py", line 39, in predict_datapoint
results=predict_pipeline.predict(pred_df)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kolhe\result_predict\src\pipeline\predict_pipeline.py", line 24, in predict
raise CustomException(e,sys)
src.exception.CustomException: Error occured in python script name [C:\Users\kolhe\result_predict\src\pipeline\predict_pipeline.py] line number [19] error message['OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute '_drop_idx_after_grouping']
[ 2024-03-23 21:25:17,425 ] 96 werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Mar/2024 21:25:17] "[35m[1mPOST /predictdata HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -

i am not able to find the problem

Comment: Hi, please refer [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Help us help you!